# Best way to prevent memory-leak when using Firebase

Tags: android, memory-leaks, firebase

In Android, when an Activity is destroyed, should I remove all the listeners

```
ref.addAuthStateListener(listener);
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(listener);
ref.addChildEventListener(listener);
ref.addValueEventListener(listener);
```

using `ref.removeEventListener(listener)` or they will be destroyed automatically?

I know that for `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` we can use `cleanup()` to do the job. 
Besides listeners and adapters are there any other objects that we need to cleanup?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firebase listeners are not automatically removed. You will indeed have to remove them by calling `removeEventListener()`, just like you add them.

Whether you remove listeners in `onDestroy()` really depends on where you add them. I typically remove them in the event that is the opposite of where I add them. So if I add then in `onCreate()`, I remove then (or call `cleanup()` in `onDestroy()`. Similar for `onStart()`/`onStop()` and `onPause()`/`onResume()`.

Comment: how about addListenerForSingleValueEvent?

Comment: That gets automatically removed **once it is triggered**. If it doesn't get triggered (i.e. if you're offline) you should still remove it. One more reasonto not use them as far as I'm concerned. :-)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen are you suggesting that using addListenerForSingleValueEvent is not good practice? As you said, it caused some trouble when I was offline.

Comment: If possible, use Firebase REST API instead: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was causing a lot of memory leaks. So I created a new class that handles added listeners and removes them when the corresponding method (onPause(), onStop() or onDestroy()) is called. Uses the [androidx.lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle) library and is applicable to both activities and fragments (in fact, any class that implements [LifecycleOwner](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/LifecycleOwner)).

You can check the code [here](https://gist.github.com/javmarina/dcb86c7fc8445a2130ea0bf136a1b859). You will probably be good to go without manually adding the androidx.lifecycle dependency, but you can also add this to your module-level build.gradle:

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:VERSION'
```

In your current code, instead of:

```
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
// or
databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

you need to use:

```
addValueEventListener(databaseReference, valueEventListener); 
// or
addListenerForSingleValueEvent(databaseReference, valueEventListener);
```

This is valid when called from activities or fragments that use FirebaseListenerHandler, as shown in the [gist](https://gist.github.com/javmarina/dcb86c7fc8445a2130ea0bf136a1b859). If you need to add a Firebase listener in another situation (like services), you still have to manually remove them.